# How to bind WPF trigger to child element

Tags: wpf, triggers, binding

I'd like to redefine the template of the menu item.

I'd like to have the icon foreground `PrimarySolidColorBrush` and the header foreground `Black` (default), but. have the background `PrimarySolidColorBrush` and  foreground `White` for the icon and the header when the mouse is over.

Currently only the header change, but it has no effect to the icon. I also tried with `DataTrigger` inside the `ControlTemplate` (binded to the parent) and used `TargetName`.

Below are the minimal lines of code:

```
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" ContentSource="Icon" TextBlock.Foreground="{StaticResource PrimarySolidColorBrush}" />
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        <Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White" /> <!-- Has no effect on the Icon textbox foreground -->
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimarySolidColorBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the local value assignment `TextBlock.Foreground="{StaticResource PrimarySolidColorBrush}"` from the `ContentPresenter` and set the default via a style setter. The `TextBlock.Foreground` property as well as the `Control.Foreground` property (both add ownership to the `TextElement.Foreground` property) is automatically inherited by the child element tree (dependency property inheritance).
This means setting `Control.Foreground` on the parent `MenuItem` will trickle down to the `ContentPresenter`.

If you set the value via the style setter, then the trigger can override this value because a trigger always has precedence over the style setter.
But if the value is set locally (like you are currently doing it for the `ContenPresenter`), the local value is dominant because it has always precedence over every non-local value, except animations and dependency property coercion (see Microsoft learn: [Dependency property precedence list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netdesktop-8.0#dependency-property-precedence-list)).

```xml
  <!-- Set the default. Will be dynamically replaced by the trigger and restored after the trigger became invalid. -->
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="{StaticResource PrimarySolidColorBrush}" />

  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          
          <!-- Foreground is inherited from the parent Grid, which itself inherits the value from the parent MenuItem -->
          <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
                            ContentSource="Icon" />
          <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" 
                            ContentSource="Header" />
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    <Setter.Value>
  </Setter>

  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" 
             Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" 
              Value="White" /> <!-- Now successfully overrides the default set by the style setter -->
      <Setter Property="Background" 
              Value="{StaticResource PrimarySolidColorBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```